# I'm trying to create my own AddOn for Home Assistant, but Im having trouble getting the docker image right

Tags: docker, home-assistant

I'm new to Home assistant and trying to set up an add-on for the first time.

This is my Docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src", ""]
COPY ["*.sln", ""]

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/FrigateSender
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build "FrigateSender.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet test "FrigateSender.sln" "--logger:trx"
WORKDIR /src/src/FrigateSender

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FrigateSender.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FrigateSender.dll"]
```

And this is the error I get.

```
#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
#3 ERROR: no match for platform in manifest sha256:19c92d0a00d1b66d897bceaa7319bee0dd38a10a851c60bcec9474aa3f01e50f: not found

#4 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
#4 CANCELED
```

The entire repository this is coming from can be viewed here:
https://github.com/InfriaAB/FrigateSender

This repository is based on the example here:
https://github.com/home-assistant/addons-example

My guess as to what is going on is that I have no idea how to set up a multi architecture Docker build, and as it tries to build for several different platforms I'm doing something wrong when I define `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base` in my Docker file. Other than that I have no idea and I have not managed to find any relevant documentation.

Comment: I only have a little add-on dev experience, but the first thing you might want to try is to use the HA provided base image. [See here for an example](https://github.com/hassio-addons/addon-ssh/blob/main/ssh/Dockerfile#L1). Also you say you get an error, but you might want to say what you're doing when you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a different approach for my Easywave2Mqtt add-on.
I build the thing in Visual Studio.NET and copy the binaries in a docker image.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 
 # Copy add-on binaries 
 ADD app /app 
 # Switch to app folder 
 WORKDIR /app 
 # Run the addon 
 CMD [ "dotnet", "Easywave2Mqtt.dll" ]
```